# Composer create the project at an unknown location

Tags: laravel, composer-php, project

I tried to execute

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel
```

It is saying that it is creating the project at "C:\Users\FXFX\" but there is no visible project at "C:\Users\FXFX\", I wonder where is my projects gone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of the "Comodo Internet security sandbox". It always sand box the composer and that resulted to creating it's files inside the sandbox in my case "C:\VTRoot\HarddiskVolume3\Users\FXFX".

**Solution** :
I exclude composer directory from the sandbox.

Comment: You realize that using any of these "security and antivirus" software actually make your system more insecure? The software usually embeds itself deep into your operating system - and it contains bugs. Now you have bugs deep inside your operating system... If on Windows, use Microsoft's Defender, and that should take you pretty far. Microsoft tends to not break their own OS with a virus scanner, because they do not embed it in places it does not belong.

Comment: Defender is useless, I know in my experience, This is the only one that hold my system virus free and it is very effective.  I have tested many.yes it has some cons but it is a risk that I am willing to take than formatting the whole system every 3 months :)